# awk/gawk - remove line if line 2 doesn't exist

Tags: awk, cygwin, gawk

I have a .txt file with 2 rows, and a seperator, some lines only contain 1 row though, so I want to remove those that only contain 1 row.

example of lines are

Line to keep,

```
Iamnotyours:email@email.com
```

Line to remove,

```
Iamnotyours:
```

Comment: From question - "remove those that only contain 1 row"
From example - "you are selecting row where you have more than 1 column"

Comment: When you say "row" do you mean "column"? Does it matter which column is empty? [edit] your question to include more comprehensive input/output showing all combinations of presence/absence in each column.

Answer (score 2):

Given your posted sample input all you need is:

```
grep -v ':$' file
```

or if you insist on awk for some reason:

```
awk '!/:$/' file
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: To make it a byte shorter (and to remove that `!`): `awk '/:./' file`.

Comment: idk if the `:` will always be there though. Not a lot of info in the question!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F: 'NF==2' file
```

prints only the lines with two fields

```
$ awk -F: 'NF>1' file
```

prints lines more than one field.  Your case, you have the separator in place, the field count will be two.   You need to check whether second field is empty

```
$ awk -F: '$2!=""' file
```